# Loops in R and adding a columns and values in a dataset

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, geospatial

I have no idea in R syntax, but I need to do simple computations with the data. I need to compute distances between objects (spatial)

```
    str(cur_slice)
    Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   489 obs. of  24         variables:
     $ MMSI       : num  2.73e+08 2.11e+08 2.72e+08 2.73e+08 2.73e+08 ...
     $ LATITUDE   : num  45.4 44.1 46.9 44.7 45.2 ...
     $ LONGITUDE  : num  36.7 28.6 32 37.8 36.5 ...
    ....
```

I need to calculate the distances between each object listed in the cur_slice table.

Trying to do temporary array for coordinates using next loops.

```
    > myarray <- NULL # Creates empty storage container
    > for (row in seq(cur_slice)) {
        cur_MMSI<- cur_slice$MMSI[raw]
        cur_lon<-cur_slice$LONGITUDE[raw]
        cur_lat<-cur_slice$LATITUDE[raw]
        for (raw2 in seq(cur_slice)) {
            if(!cur_slice$MMSI[raw2]==cur_MMSI) {
                myarray<-c(myarray, cur_MMSI, cur_slice$MMSI[raw2], cur_lat, cur_lon, cur_slice$LATITUDE[raw2], cur_slice$LONGITUDE[raw2])
            }
        }
     }
```

But:

1. I don't get the data in a table (myarray is simple list). How can I get a table, not a list?
2. my overall array is too big. E.g. in the sample cur_slice I have 489 objects... in overall array I have: 31962456 items... I understand that it's not rows, it's only items...

How can I read data from one table and add it into another table (for future computation) and is there need to use for?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way with least edits to your code to have a table out of your loops.

```
mydf <- data.frame() # Creates empty dataframe
for (row in seq(cur_slice)) {
  cur_MMSI<- cur_slice$MMSI[raw]
  cur_lon<-cur_slice$LONGITUDE[raw]
  cur_lat<-cur_slice$LATITUDE[raw]
  for (raw2 in seq(cur_slice)) {
    if(!cur_slice$MMSI[raw2]==cur_MMSI) {
      mydf<-rbind(mydf, data.frame(cur_MMSI, cur_slice$MMSI[raw2], cur_lat, cur_lon, cur_slice$LATITUDE[raw2], cur_slice$LONGITUDE[raw2]))
    }
  }
}
```

**However this is extremely bad code**

1. It's got a `for loop`
2. It's got a nested `for loop`
3. `rbind()` on a data.frame inside a loop is very time consuming because it reallocates the memory needed for the whole table each iteration

Comment: how can i do this code faster? how can i delete nested loops and for? and is it possible to add data to dataframe dynamically but fast enough?? :)

Comment: Sure, can you share the logic you're trying to apply in simple words?

Comment: now i tried to deploy the next code:
         for (i in 1:nrow(cur_slice)) {
+     cur_MMSI<-cur_slice[i, "MMSI"]
+     cur_lon<-cur_slice[i,"LONGITUDE"]
+     cur_lat<-cur_slice[i,"LATITUDE"]
+     for (j in 1:nrow(cur_slice)) {
+         if(!cur_slice[j,"MMSI"]==cur_MMSI) {
+             mydf<-rbind(mydf, data.frame(cur_MMSI, cur_slice[j,"MMSI"], cur_lat, cur_lon))
+         }
+     }
+ }
    
ant it still works .... very slow ... and i have only 489 rows in my cur_slice dataframe,

Comment: Basic logic: i need to get pairs of all the rows to compute distance between them. Coordinates of the objects identified by the MMSI field are provided in LATITUDE and LOGITUDE fields of the dataframe,

I need to compute distances between all different MMSI. e.g. first and second raw, first and third..,,, So i need to collect data to a new dataframe with mmsi1, mmsi2, lon1,lat1, lon2, lat2 fields. Is it clear?

on the next stage i will compute geographical distance using prepared data...